# Converting Phonegap app datetime fields to work on ios7

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, datetime, cordova

So I just found out that the datetime input fields I use all over my app are no longer working on IOS7, so I found that the datetime-local input type is still supported.  Timezone is not important to the function of my app, so this is ok.  The problem is, the code I was using to populate and retrieve the date values from the input fields does not work.  Here is my code:

```
$("#date").val(pv.When);
```

To set it, where date is the id of my input and pv.When is a datetime object

```
theVisit.When = new Date($("#date").val());
```

To retrieve it, right now neither do anything, the field is empty when i load the form, and the value does not save.  Do I need to do anything special to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, what I did was this, I wrote 2 utility functions, one to set the value of the datetime-local field and one to get the value out as a date.  You will notice as part of the fix I am using the Moment.js date helper library.

Here are my 2 functions:

```
    function getDateTimeForPicker(d) {
        var offset = d.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
        d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - d.getTimezoneOffset())
        return d.toISOString().replace("Z", "");
    }
    function getDateTimeFromPicker(d) {
        var m = moment(d);
        var ret = m.toDate();
        return ret;
    }
```

so I can set as easy as :

```
$("#dateTimeBox").val(getDateTimeForPicker(new Date()));
```

This is tested and working fine on iOS7